# Algorithm to identify marked similarities in html

Tags: html, algorithm, machine-learning, similarity

I would like to find similarities (exactly the patterns of it) in one or more 
HTML pages without knowing thier structure.

Lets talk about a really simplified example where the content and all attributes are
removed.

```
01 <div>
02  <div><table>.*</table></div>
03  <div><table>.*</table></div>
04
05  <div><p></p><img/></div>
06  <div><p></p><img/></div>
07  <div><p></p><img/></div>    
08
09  <div><table>.*</table></div>
10  <div><table>.*</table></div>
11 </div>
```

We (humans) can see that there are two differnt types of patterns. The 
first one (with the table) occurs four times. And there is an 
other one with an image tag, three times. That is easy (for humans).

The perfect module, I would like to write, would return a resultset like:

```
$VAR = [ { reduced_pattern => '<div><table>.*</table>div>',
           real_pattern => '<!-- the real pattern -->',
           hits => [{ line => 02,
                      content => "<div><table>foo 1</table></div>",
                      relevance => 0,9,
                    },
                    { line => 03,
                      content => "<div><table>foo 2</table></div>",
                      relevance => 0,95,
                    },   
                    { line => 09,
                      content => "<div><table>foo 3</table></div>",
                      relevance => 0,87
                    },
                    { line => 10,
                      content => "<div><table>foo 4</table></div>",
                      relevance => 0,80
                    }
                   ]
         }, 
         { real_pattern => '<!-- the real pattern -->',
                 hits => [{ line => 05,
                      content => "<div><p>bar 1</p><img/></div>",
                      relevance => 0,79,
                    },
                    { line => 06,
                      content => "<div><p>bar 2</p><img/></div>",
                      relevance => 0,95,
                    },   
                    { line => 07,
                      content => "<div><p>bar 3</p><img/></div>",
                      relevance => 0,80
                    }
                   ],
         }
        ];
```

Something like that.

The question is about the algorithm. I searched for 'Algorithm to identify marked similarities.' and alike sentences on the web, here on SO and on CPAN, but did not find something that matched well. (I know there are a lot and I read a lot of them.)

RegExp does not come in consideration, because you have to know what you are searching for.
I assume that it can be done with neuronal networks, but the learning is may be difficult. 
Also Fuzzy Hashes (like in sssdeep) may be a solution. Or should I better start in the direction of k-means or mahout?

Thanks for your answers and comments!

Comment: still not really sure what you want to achieve, anyway i would go for some easy ml algorithm e.g. decision trees where you can see how a decision was made ....

Comment: Yeah, same here, don't really understand the question..

Comment: If you want similarity depending on the HTML structure, you might want to consider **tree mining** (search that on scholar.google.com). To make use of actual content, combine it with bag-of-words approach with a machine learning method of your choice. Just some generic ideas here.

Comment: @Timo: I will have a closer look at tree mining. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can use the longest common subsequence algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I too am struggling a little to completely understand your question, however one such algorithm to look into may be [Support Vector Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) if you are looking to classify pages into two separate types. If you are able to produce pre-categorised datasets then [Hidden Markov Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) may be the way to go. As xhudik suggested, even Decision Trees could be used.

Apologies if you are looking for a specific answer, but I think more information is required (eg. 2-3 html examples and how you those are to be categorised) to pinpoint what you want to achieve.

Edit: Also, have you looked into [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)? Products such as [Weka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_%28machine_learning%29) and [Orange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_%28software%29) could help you if what you want is intelligent statistical grouping.

Comment: SVM sounds interesting, but i do not want to predict something. The result should be calculated on exisiting values. I'm not sure about HMM, but ML and sounds good. That would be searching for the LCS in the tree. But it should be avoided that the sequences overlap.

Comment: After reading the comments and the related articles i came (back) to a graph. I think the best description of what I want to do is: Find common subtrees in a directed graph, where the paths do not overlap.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much in the way of graphs in Machine Learning. I would say Timo's suggestion above seems the most appropriate from what I can tell.